# Android Gallery Adapter with MultiTouch? Custom Gallery or Custom ImageView?

Tags: android, android-widget

I would like to recreate the same type of app as Gallery3D but simpler: without the 3D animations and basically only keep GridView and Gallery widgets. I would also like to enable multi-touch zooming-dragging-scolling on the selected image and that's where I am struggling. I looked online for simple tutorials and I also looked at the Gallery3D source code but couldn't find a proper solution.

The closest I could get was using the custom ImageView below in my Gallery Adapter.

It works, I can pinch-and-zoom and drag except that the image goes off the screen and I can't scroll to the next image in the gallery. Also pinch-and-zoom is not perfect because it only scales the image and does not recenter it properly. Should I be adding an onTouchEvent on the Gallery instead ?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;

public class MyImageView extends View {

private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

    private BitmapDrawable mImage;
    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

    public MyImageView(Context context, BitmapDrawable bd) {
        this(context, null, 0);
     mImage = bd;
        mImage.setBounds(0, 0, mImage.getIntrinsicWidth(), mImage.getIntrinsicHeight());
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
            final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

            // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
            if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                invalidate();
            }

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                    >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }
            break;
        }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();
        Log.d("DEBUG", "X: "+mPosX+" Y: "+mPosY);
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        mImage.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at both of these tutorials, which I found very helpful:

- [One Finger Zooming and Panning](http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/wp/2010/05/18/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-1/#more-265)
- [Pinch Zoom Gesture](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747?tag=mantle_skin;content)

By the way, neither of them uses the ScaleGestureDetector, but the achieved effects are very neat though.